# Use CiviCRM and FluentSMTP

Tags: email

I would like to use CiviCRM with FluentSMTP (WordPress installation). The goal is to reliably send out emails from CiviCRM that are not blocked by email providers or sent straight to junk. I have setup FluentSMTP and my understanding is that it intercepts all mail sent using wp_mail and uses the connectors setup to push that mail out. If I test send from FluentSMTP, it works perfectly. Going to send mail from CiviCRM seems to bypass FluentSMTP. I cannot setup using SMTP directly in CiviCRM since my webhost block SMTP traffic out. I have to use an API (hence why I am trying to use FluentSMTP).

How can I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: you'd need to write a CiviCRM extension. There are some similar extensions that you could use for a model/inspiration.

BUT ...

Usually, php applications (like Drupal or Wordpress) rely on php mail handling to send out mail, which is why you need FluentSMTP to hook in to other services to send out mail from wordpress if your standard outgoing mail is normally blocked by your provider.

CiviCRM though, is already quite sophisticated, so you don't need to use FluentSMTP to intercept the php mail calls since CiviCRM doesn't use the php mail() function. Instead, you can set up civicrm to send out with most of the same methods/services that fluentSMTP does, ie. using sendgrid, sparkpost, mailgun, or one of those other services that shall not be named, by installing an eponymous extension.

Try looking here: https://civicrm.org/extensions

Longer answer: you probably don't want to bother, use one of the existing CiviCRM extensions for sending out mail via the same (or a different) service you're using with FluentSMTP.